# Linked list problems with node deletion function

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, delete-operator

I'm currently working on a linked list that stores even integers at the front of the list and odd integers at the back. Everything is working fine for me, except for my deletion function, whereby it takes user input on whether they want to delete an even or an odd integer, and uses that as a prompt to either delete from the front or back of the list. Here is the code I have for my node deletion function:

```
void Staque::pop(char EvenOrOdd)
{
    if (!empty())
    {
        if (EvenOrOdd == 'O' || 'o')
        {
            //Creating pointers to find end of Staque
            Staque::NodePointer prevPtr = myTop, //Pointer to find penultimate Node and set "next" value to 0
                currentPtr = myTop; //Pointer to find Node to delete

            //Assigning pointers to corresponding nodes
            while (prevPtr->next->next != 0)
            {
                prevPtr = prevPtr->next;
            }
            while (currentPtr->next != 0)
            {
                currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
            }

            //Deleting the last node in the Staque and setting "next" value of new end to 0
            delete currentPtr;
            prevPtr->next = 0;
        }
        else if (EvenOrOdd == 'e' || 'E')
        {
            Staque::NodePointer ptr = myTop;
            myTop = myTop->next;
            delete ptr;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Stack is empty -- can't remove a value \n";
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't take the input on deciding what kind of element to delete. It just deletes whatever I put first in the if construct of the node deletion function. If, in that if construct, I have the code for deleting evens above the code for deleting odds, it'll only delete evens, and vice versa. Please help, I can't figure out why it's doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if (EvenOrOdd == 'O' || 'o')
```

to

```
if (EvenOrOdd == 'O' || EvenOrOdd == 'o')
```

Similar for another one, i.e. `else if (EvenOrOdd == 'e' || 'E')`.

---

Note that, for

```
if (EvenOrOdd == 'O' || 'o')
```

this is same to

```
if (EvenOrOdd == 'O' || (bool)'o')
```

further to

```
if (EvenOrOdd == 'O' || true)
```

further to

```
if (true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe something like that slipped my mind after I looked through it so many times. I need to work on being more careful with my syntax.